# full calendar always shows all events

Tags: php, sql, fullcalendar

I have an issue with my full calendar, so everything is working when I want to add events.
My problem occurs with categories. So when the calendar loads, it shows all the events which is perfect. However, when I change the category in my category select, it still shows every event. I really don't know why it doesn't update because when I execute:

```
$this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection,
"SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $this->condition");
```

And then:

```
var_dump($this->result);
```

I have the good numbers of events:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5)
{
   ["current_field"]=> int(0)
   ["field_count"]=> int(9)
   ["lengths"]=> NULL 
   ["num_rows"]=> int(3)
   ["type"]=> int(0) 
}
```

3 here, and it still shows 8 events.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to work with this.

The problem was that i got the sql result from my database and not the json array with all the datas. So i just passed my calendar object build with the result to my json function :

```
        /**
    * Function To Transform MySQL Results To jQuery Calendar Json
    * Returns converted json
    */
    public function json_transform($calendar,$js = true)
    {

        while($this->row = mysqli_fetch_array($calendar->result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
             // Set Variables Data from DB
             $event_id = $this->row['id'];
             $event_title = $this->row['title'];
             $event_description = $this->row['description'];
             $event_start = $this->row['start'];
             $event_end = $this->row['end'];
             $event_allDay = $this->row['allDay'];
             $event_color = $this->row['color'];
             $event_url = $this->row['url'];
             $event_society = $this->row['category'];

             if($js == true) 
             {
                 // JS MODE
                 // When allDay = false the allDay options appears on the script, when its true it doesnot appear 
                 if($event_url == 'false' && $event_allDay == 'false')
                 {
                     // Build it Without URL & allDay

                     // Stores Each Database Record To An Array (Without URL)
                    $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'description' => $event_description, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'allDay' => $event_allDay, 'color' => $event_color);

                    // Adds Each Array Into The Container Array
                    array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);

                 } elseif($event_url == 'false' && $event_allDay == 'true') {

                     // Build it Without URL 

                     // Stores Each Database Record To An Array (Without URL)

                    $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'description' => $event_description, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'color' => $event_color);

                    // Adds Each Array Into The Container Array
                    array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);


                 } elseif($event_url == 'true' && $event_allDay == 'false') {

                     // Built it Without URL & allDay True

                    // Stores Each Database Record To An Array
                    $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'description' => $event_description, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'allDay' => $event_allDay, 'color' => $event_color, 'url' => $event_url);

                    // Adds Each Array Into The Container Array
                    array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);

                 } else {

                     if($event_allDay == 'false') {
                        // Built it With URL & allDay false

                        // Stores Each Database Record To An Array
                        $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'description' => $event_description, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'allDay' => $event_allDay, 'color' => $event_color, 'url' => $event_url);

                        // Adds Each Array Into The Container Array
                        array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);
                     } else {
                        // Built it With URL & allDay True

                        // Stores Each Database Record To An Array
                        $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'description' => $event_description, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'color' => $event_color, 'url' => $event_url);

                        // Adds Each Array Into The Container Array
                        array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);  
                     }


                 }
             }
       }
```

And then with this array i just refresh my calendar :

```
            if(opt.filter == true)
        {
            $(opt.formFilterSelector).on('change', function(e) 
            {

                 selected_value = $(this).val();

                 construct = 'filter='+selected_value;
                 $.post('includes/cal_events.php', construct, function(response) 
                {
                     $(opt.calendarSelector).fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                     var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                     $(opt.calendarSelector).fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', obj);

                });                  
                 e.preventDefault();  
            });
        }
```

cal_events.php file calls the json function.
You need to convert the json array to javascript with this : **var obj = $.parseJSON(response);** to get this working.

Hope this will help.